# CSS stop text re-sizing to very bottom

Tags: css, html, text, constraints

What I'm looking to do is stop it overflowing to the very bottom of the page as I want a div at the bottom for other things. So how do I leave a gap between the text and the bottom of the page?

Also how to I constrain text to the size and position of a div? The element is about 20 pixels under the div and is causing overlap issues.

HTML:

```
<div id="Info">
    "a lot of text here"
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#Info { 
    background-color:#000; 
    position:absolute;
    top:200px; 
    left:20%;
    height:50%; 
    width:60%;
    color:#FFF;
    font-size:18px;
    font-weight:bold;
    z-index:110;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a demo of what you have, like jsfiddle.

Comment: Is it typo in `.#Info` or you are using class and id selector together?

Comment: no that was my fault im not sure if this site uses code tags or not so put a . to stop it being weird.

Comment: This would be easier to understand (and solve) if you could show us an example. An fiddle or even an image would help.

Comment: I have added your code in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b3Eft/) it would be good if you can add image of your expected output

Comment: http://officialacescottie.co.uk/Home/Home.html best example i can give.

Comment: and i simply want it not to go in the last 15% of the bottom of the page. so even if the page is 19 miles long it will never use up that 15% at the bottom.

Answer (score 1):

You said "The element is about 20 pixels under the div and is causing overlap issues." Have you tried adding margin-bottom: 20px; to your id? Or however many px you need.

Comment: no that dose not seem to work. its not that there is not margin its just the text ignores the div completely.

Comment: looking at your code from chrome i see your text is not wrapped in a paragraph tag <p> might try that. Also might try height auto for your id. I am new to coding but these are just things I would try. Will keep trying to help.